# How to display text in markdown format programmatically in Docusaurus

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

In MXD file I get a text via rest-call and can display it as code-block shown [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/code-blocks#usage-in-jsx) with `<CodeBlock>` component, which works fine.

Is there a way or component to display a text fetched via rest-call as `markdown` page programmatically?

Comment: Docusaurus renderers the markdown **offline**. So I believe that what you want is not possible this way. But you may try using this [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) plugin to render markdown pages on-demand.

Comment: What do you mean by "Docusaurus renderers the markdown offline"? Thx, I could get the job done with react-markdown!

Comment: Docusaurus is a tool to generate a website (HTML, CSS, JS) using your markdown files. Thus, it doesn't renders those files "on the fly". I am glad to know!